# Textview Frame is become squeez and cannot come back to its original form?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, uitextview

[image]

[image]

**keyboardWillShow** method implementation :

```
 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification 
    {

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     CGRect endRect = [[notification.userInfo 
     objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
      CGRect newRect = txtNotes.frame;
      //Down size your text view
      newRect.size.height -= endRect.size.height;
      txtNotes.frame = newRect;
      [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

**keyboardWillHide** method implementation :

```
  - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
      // Resize your textview when keyboard is going to hide
       UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
       txtNotes.contentInset = contentInsets;
       txtNotes.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) META: You should add 4 spaces before each of the code lines to get the code to display properly.

2) This looks like a basic constraints issue. You should examine the [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) of your storyboard.